# How to customize the margin, padding and fontsize of a TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to customize the fontsize, margin and padding of the TextField to make it apper bigger. Could you please guide me on how to customize it. I tried to customize it with className but the inset text appears outside the outline.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ad24ce

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the width of the Textfield by the standard style and the height and text size could be modified by the prop `InputProps`. The margin and padding would simply move the textfield around the DOM. As far as size goes, it would go something like this for the Textfield style:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  // ...
  textField: {
    width: 500 // or width of choice
    // margin: if needed
    // padding: if needed
  },
  resize: {
    fontSize: 50 // or size of choice
  }
}));
```

And the `InputProps` on the Textfield:

```
    <TextField
      required
      id="standard-required"
      label="Required"
      defaultValue="Hello World"
      className={classes.textField}
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth={true}
      InputProps={{
        classes: {
          input: classes.resize,
        }
      }}
    />
```